# angle effect on drop shadow using CSS3

Tags: css

I would like to create a shadow similar to the one on the slider at [http://www.thegrovechurch.org.](http://www.thegrovechurch.org)

I have recreated it in Photoshop, but I'm unsure of how to do it with pure CSS, which would be preferable.

Comment: This is probably possible nowadays. Similar effects in pure css: http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, nearly close to that ;)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QEm24/1/)

```
.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #000;
}
```

Comment: this is closer to what I'm after, and I tried this method, but it just doesn't quite have the angle to it on the ends of the shadow.

Comment: @user1476992 ya but CSS cannot do everything what a photoshop can do so this is near close ;)

Comment: CSS can do a lot...http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

Comment: @user1476992 but that was same like mine :)

Comment: right, but the one labeled "perspective" seems to be at least somewhat similar to what i'm talking about.  It just seems that if you can do that, then why couldn't you do the one I'm looking for??

Comment: I guess I'll just stick with my photoshop shadow for now...thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generator, so you can customize your shadow however you like:

http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with CSS. http://www.thegrovechurch.org/ uses an image.

You might be able to produce something similar if you used a language that can actually do some heavy lifting in the math department - jquery and javascript would be the next places I looked, and if not there then a java applet - but even then I would worry that it would be too cumbersome and slow for most browsers to handle.